# Models from brms package is not compiling

Tags: r, brms

I am currently trying to use the "brms" package to run hierarchical models. Unfortunately, when I try to compile my model I get the following error message:

```
make cmd is
  make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.0/share/make/winshlib.mk" CXX='$(CXX14) $(CXX14STD)' CXXFLAGS='$(CXX14FLAGS)' CXXPICFLAGS='$(CXX14PICFLAGS)' SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXX14LDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXX14LD)' SHLIB="file9642842353.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN= OBJECTS="file9642842353.o"

make would use
if test "zfile9642842353.o" != "z"; then \
  if test -e "file9642842353-win.def"; then \
    echo g++  -shared -s -static-libgcc -o file9642842353.dll file9642842353-win.def file9642842353.o  -L"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/x64" -L"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib"  -L"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.0/bin/x64" -lR ; \
    g++  -shared -s -static-libgcc -o file9642842353.dll file9642842353-win.def file9642842353.o  -L"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/x64" -L"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib"  -L"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.0/bin/x64" -lR ; \
  else \
    echo EXPORTS > tmp.def; \
    nm file9642842353.o | sed -n 's/^.* [BCDRT] / /p' | sed -e '/[.]refptr[.]/d' -e '/[.]weak[.]/d' | sed 's/[^ ][^ ]*/"&"/g'  >> tmp.def; \
    echo g++  -shared -s -static-libgcc -o file9642842353.dll tmp.def file9642842353.o  -L"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/x64" -L"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib"  -L"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.0/bin/x64" -lR ; \
    g++  -shared -s -static-libgcc -o file9642842353.dll tmp.def file9642842353.o  -L"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/x64" -L"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib"  -L"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.0/bin/x64" -lR ; \
    rm -f tmp.def; \
  fi \
fi
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  C:\rtools43\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: file9642842353.o:file9642842353:(.text$_ZN3tbb8internal26task_scheduler_observer_v3D0Ev[_ZN3tbb8internal26task_scheduler_observer_v3D0Ev]+0x1c): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::task_scheduler_observer_v3::observe(bool)'C:\rtools43\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: file9642842353.o:file9642842353:(.text$_ZN3tbb10interface623task_scheduler_observerD1Ev[_ZN3tbb10interface623task_scheduler_observerD1Ev]+0x1c): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::task_scheduler_observer_v3::observe(bool)'C:\rtools43\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: file9642842353.o:file9642842353:(.text$_ZN3tbb10interface623task_scheduler_observerD1Ev[_ZN3tbb10interface623task_scheduler_observerD1Ev]+0x37): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::task_scheduler_observer_v3::observe(bool)'C:\rtools43\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: file9642842353.o:file9642842353:(.text$_ZN3tbb10interface623task_scheduler_observerD0Ev[_
Error in sink(type = "output") : invalid connection
```

I tried different approaches of installing all necessary packages like rstan and StanHeaders, also updated RTools to 4.3, but nothing works. I am basically looking for a solution to run the model on my local machine.

Comment: See https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Configuring-C---Toolchain-for-Windows, do you have `rstan` v2.26?

Comment: I did try this approach, but was installing the version for 4.2, while already having the 4.3 Version of R. Thank you very much, this solved my problem :)